# オブジェクト内で定義したコールバック関数でオブジェクトのプロパティを変更する方法

Tags: javascript

MonacaクラウドでOnsenUI/AngularJSを使いアプリ制作の勉強中です。

ファイルを扱うAngularJSサービスオブジェクトを作っています。
フォルダのファイル一覧を取得するメソッドの中でFileSystemAPIを使うため
コールバック関数を使わなくてはならないのですが、その中でファイル一覧を格納するプロパティ(this.x)を書き換えようとすると以下のようなエラーが出ます(use strict)。

> Error in Success callbackId: FileXXXXXXXXXX : TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.

JavaScriptの仕様のようですが、コールバック関数内でプロパティを変更する
スマートな回避方法があればお教え頂けると幸いです。

再現する簡略化したコードを追記いたします。
実際にはエラー発生箇所でディレクトリの中身をプロパティに設定したいと考えております。

```
var obj = function() {
    'use strict';

    this.directory = '';

    this.changeDirectory = function(directory, returnFunction){
        this.directory = directory; //問題なし
        pstFileSystem.root.getDirectory(directory, {create: true, exclusive: false},
            function(dirEntry){
                this.directory = directory; //エラー
                returnFunction(dirEntry);
            }
        );
    };
};

window.onload = function() {
    'use strict';

    console.log('pageinit start!');
    var o = new obj;
    o.changeDirectory("/", function(dirEntry){console.log('directory is "' + o.directory + '"');});
};
```

Comment: コールバックから書き換えようとしているのが問題ではなくて、「読み取り専用の」プロパティを書き換えようとしているのが問題であるように見えます。
これ以上は、実際のコードを見てみないとなんとも言えません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！
コードを追記いたしました。

何かおわかりになりましたら是非宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: ありがとうございます!
ふむ、調べてみたところ `getDirectory` のコールバック関数の `this` はグローバル オブジェクト (ブラウザなら `window`) ですね。なんで読み取り専用なんてエラーが出たのかわからないです ^^;;
とはいえ、今回の質問の回答には関係なさそうなので、それはスルーで....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

外側のスコープの `this` にアクセスする方法は、方法は3つあります。

ひとつめ。ローカル変数に外側のスコープの `this` を保管して、それを使う。

```
var self = this;
...
function(dirEntry){
  self.directory = directory;
  returnFunction(dirEntry);
}
```

ふたつめ。コールバック関数の `this` に外側のスコープの `this` を [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) する。

```
function(dirEntry){
  this.directory = directory;
  returnFunction(dirEntry);
}.bind(this)
```

このようにすると、コールバック関数の `this` は外側のスコープの `this` と同じオブジェクトになります。(IE9以降で動作します)

みっつめ。 ES2015 (ES6) で追加された ArrowFunction を使う。

```
(dirEntry) => {
  this.directory = directory;
  returnFunction(dirEntry);
}
```

ArrowFunction では、`this` は外側のスコープのものがそのまま使われます。(Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Opera で動作します)

Answer (score 2):

`this` が指すものはその関数が実行されるタイミングで決定するので、コールバック設定時の `this` と一致することを期待してはいけません。

[JavaScript の this キーワードは何を指すのか - コールバック関数内では this を使ってはいけない - vivid memo](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/vividcode/20110106/1294336737)

この場合 `this` を他の変数に保存しておいて、コールバック関数内ではそれを使うとよいでしょう。

```
this.changeDirectory = function(directory, returnFunction){
    var self = this; //この時点でのthisを保存
    pstFileSystem.root.getDirectory(directory, {create: true, exclusive: false},
        function(dirEntry){
            self.directory = directory;
            returnFunction(dirEntry);
        }
    );
};
```

例:

```js
var Hoge = function() {
  this.prop = "OK";
  this.run = function() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('body').html(
        'this: ' + this.prop + "<br/>" +
        'self: ' + self.prop
      );
    }, 0);
  };
};

var o = new Hoge();
o.run();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

なお、 `this` を保存するタイミングは `changeDirectory` の外側、 `obj` の中でも構いません。